# Upload image to Azure blob with summernote

Tags: azure, file-upload, summernote

```
public class StorageService
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=removed for this post");

        public async Task Upload(string id, Stream data)
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            container.SetPermissions(
                new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(id);

            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(data, data.Length);
        }

        public async Task UploadBlogPhoto(string id, Stream data)
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            container.SetPermissions(
                new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(id);

            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(data, data.Length);
        }
    }
```

So I have the StorageServices class and I use the first method, Upload, to upload users' profile pics.

here is the markup:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="browseimg">
                    <input type="file" class="display-none" name="file" id="files" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
                </div>
            }
            <button class="btn btn-primary width-100p main-bg round-border-bot" id="falseFiles">
                Upload billede
            </button>
```

[image]

This is the summernote button for uploading a photo. The post uploads to a database. However, is there a way for the text to be uploaded to the database and the image to Azure blob? Would I need to do it asynchronously by first uploading the picture and adding the azure blob's URL into summernote, can it be done?

Comment: I have not used Summernote so I don't know how exactly it works but considering Azure Blob Storage and Summernote are two different data stores, you would need to perform two operations: One to upload the blob and then to write into this Summernote database. Though you can perform both operations in your Upload functions only. First upload the image in blob storage, wait for it to complete and then insert text.

Answer (score 1):

As Gaurav said, you could perform both operations in your upload functions. In my opinion, I recommend that you perform both operations in your upload action, in order to ensure data consistency. Here I provide you with a code sample to have a better understanding of it.

**ManageController.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Upload photo with description
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imageNote">description of the photo</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<JsonResult> UploadPhoto(string imageNote)
{
    string operationResult = string.Empty;
    string uploadedImageUrl = string.Empty;
    uploadedImageUrl = await UploadImageToBlob();
    //make sure the image is uploaded successfully to Azure Blob
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadedImageUrl))
    {
        //insert the image(blob) Url and imageNote to your database
        operationResult = "Operation is successful!";
    }
    else
        operationResult = "Image upload failed, please check and submit again!";

    return Json(new
    {
        Message = operationResult
    });
}

/// <summary>
/// Upload photo to Azure Blob Storage
/// </summary>
/// <returns>the new Blob(photo) Url</returns>
private async Task<string> UploadImageToBlob()
{
    string uploadedImageUrl = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var files = Request.Files;
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = files[0];
            string blobName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            #region upload image to Azure Blob and retrieve the Blob Url
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("brucechenStorage"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "blobName".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.InputStream);
            uploadedImageUrl = blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
            #endregion
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //TODO:log
    }
    return uploadedImageUrl;
}
```